# C Unix Millisecond Timer returning difference of 0

Tags: c, unix, timer

Can anyone explain why I always get a time of 0 from the code below? I just want a millisecond timer to calculate the delay between sending and receiving data from a socket but no matter what I try, I always get a result of 0...I even tried microseconds just in case my system was executing it in less than 1ms.

```
    printf("#: ");

    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

    struct timeval start, end;

    unsigned long mtime, seconds, useconds;    

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);  

    n = write(clientSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer));

    if (n < 0)
    {
        error("Error: Unable to write to socket!\n");
    }

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(clientSocket,buffer,255);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

    mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;      

    if (n < 0) 
    {
        error("Error: Unable to read from socket!\n");
    }

    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    printf("Delay: %lu microseconds\n", useconds);
```

Comment: Because the reading takes less than 1 millisecond, perhaps?

Comment: "I even tried microseconds just in case my system was executing it in less than 1ms." Any other suggestions?

Comment: How did you try microseconds? (And you know that these functions don't actually have microsecond resolution?)

Comment: According to [link](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) useconds is the microsecond measurement variable, which I used in the code above.

Comment: @H2CO3: `gettimeofday` has full microsecond resolution on any decent system. And `clock_gettime` has full nanosecond resolution.

Comment: @R.. Sorry, but are you sure? Last time I've checked this was not the case on Linux and OS X.

Comment: @H2CO3: I can't speak for OSX, but on Linux x86 and x86_64, all clocks have nanosecond resolution. On other archs it varies; usually the realtime clock as microsecond resolution or better, but the cpu-time clocks can be as bad as the kernel jiffy rate (typically 100 hz) on some archs.

Comment: Why dont' you try a sleep in between and then check if the difference reflects anything or not?

Comment: The sleep made no difference, still come out to 0 when I used `sleep(5)` and I know the sleep worked as it took noticably longer to return.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result is in mtime:
mtime is integer and you calculate elapsed time with float numbers so if

```
((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5
```

evaluates to < 1.0 casting to integer will cut it to 0

simply change mtime type to float, or if you can keep micro seconds use

```
((seconds) * 1000000 + useconds) + 500
```

Comment: So how do I fix it then?

Comment: solution added to answer

Answer (score 0):

`useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;` is questionable with
`unsigned long useconds;` since the result may well be negative.

Suggestion:

```
unsigned long end_us,start_us,elapsed_us;

   .
   .
   .

end_us     = end.tv_sec   * 1000000  +  end.tv_usec;
start_us   = start.tv_sec * 1000000  +  start.tv_usec;

elapsed_us = end_us - start_us;

printf("elapsed microseconds: %lu\n", elapsed_us);
```

And:

```
mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;
```

is to be looked at too: This attempts to convert to milliseconds. It is not clear why you add 0.5.

Suggestion:

```
elapsed_ms = elapsed_us / 1000;
```

But defining `elapsed_ms` as an integer would unnecessarily cut the result to full milliseconds. A float may be considered here.